# Where to Initialize Semantic UI Dropdown in React

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

In Semantic UI, you need to run

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
```

In order for your dropdown menu to function. I'm currently making it work by

```
//react onClick function
handleDropDown() {
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
}

//menu container
<div className="ui selection dropdown" onClick={this.handleDropDown}>
```

My problem is that I have to click the menu twice for it to start. Once for it to run the function, then the second will actually open the menu. How do I get it to run when the page loads?

When I try putting it into componentWillMount or componentDidMount it throws me an error saying: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

Ideas?

Comment: `componentDidMount()`: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount

Comment: I said at the bottom of my post I tried that already..

Comment: Oh hmm didn't see that. That's definitely not normal --- how are you including jquery?

Comment: Yeah because in my post I showed that code, handleDropDown, and that works. I just have to click the dropdown menu twice. Once to load/fire, second to get the menu to dropdown

Comment: Right, but there's absolutely no good reason why `componentDidMount` would cause undefined jquery error, which makes me think you're including jquery in an odd way, maybe after your react bundle

Comment: Damn, I feel so dumb.. moving my bundle below jquery worked. Thanks a ton.

Comment: pro tip.. `npm install jquery` then `import $ from 'jquery'`

Answer (score 0):

My current code:

ReactJS:

```
componentDidMount() {
    $(this._select).dropdown();
}
render() {
    return <div ref={select => this._select = select } className="ui selection dropdown">...
}
```

You setup a `ref` on render and then use that to reference the element on `componentDidMount()`

Comment: I'm still getting the error:    Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: That means that you're not including jQuery properly. How are you doing it right now?

Comment: Yeah.. sadly I found out that my bundle was above my jquery script tag.. using componentDidMount makes it work without using the ref. Thanks for your help though!